# Can the inhomogeneous system $Ax=b$ be solved if $|A| = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read in this [page](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-b-matrices-and-systems-of-equations/session-14-solutions-to-square-systems/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_m3.pdf) that if $|A|=0$ , then $Ax=b$ **usually** has no solutions,  but has solutions for some b.

I was thinking that the inhomogeneous system $Ax=b$  **always** has no solution if $|A|=0$ .

Can the inhomogeneous system  $Ax=b$ be solved if $|A| = 0$?

Comment: The page you are listing uses pretty strange mathematical language. The equation "usually" has no solution is a strange way of putting it. I would say "the equation only has a solution for particular values of $b$", and it wouldn't hurt to mention that the set of solutions is then always infinite, and of the form $\{v + w| w\in V\}$ for some vector space $V$ and some fixed vector $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 
$$A=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\\
b=(1,1)^T$$

This has lots of solutions, but if $b=(a,b)$ with $a \neq b$ it is inconsistent.

Comment: To understand recursion, you must understand recursion. :)